# How to choose whether or not use a MVC 3 Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following editor template

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

This cause that every DateTime? is shown as a ToShortDateString() "without the hour" and with the class datePicker.

But now I have the situation that for some DateTime? I need the hour.

The question is, how can I disable the editor template for individual cases? Or is there a work around for this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your model you can use `UIHint` attribute to say which editor template to use.

So you could create a new editorfor and call it something like DateTimeWithHour (or some better name!) and then in your model it will be something like:

```
[UIHint("DateTimeWithHour")]
public DateTime SomeDateTime { get; set; }
```

If you don't specify a UIHint it will default to your already created datetime editor for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **UIHintAttribute** to apply different templates on a case by case basis.
You could also pass some additional data (ie. format options) in **ViewBag**, I think.